# How Does a New Wallet Get Added to a dApp’s List of Support Wallets?

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

Let's say I have a new wallet that I've created and I wanted it to show up next to Metamask whenever a user clicks "Connect Wallet" on a dApp front-end as another wallet option.  What is the procedure for doing this?

Comment: I think you have to contact the dApp owner. Because it's their frontend logic

Comment: You might want to look at web3 Modal

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [EIP-1193](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/9e393a79d9937f579acbdcb234a67869259d5a96/EIPS/eip-1193.md) which allows Dapp to interact with different providers. Essentially, your wallet should follow the standard to be compatible with the Dapp in the market.

Taking [Metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/create-dapp.html#basic-action-part-1) as an example, after it is installed, there is a global object available at the front-end named Ethereum.

```
//Have to check the ethereum binding on the window object to see if it's installed
const { ethereum } = window;
```

Dapps interact with this object to interact with the blockchain without knowing the users' private keys and other sensitive information. If additional information is required, Webapp can retrieve it through Metamask's APIs.

As others suggest, if you don't own the Dapp, you need to talk to the owner to add your wallet as one of the options.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. The dApp frontend controls the shots there, so the only way is to have them integrating with your wallet, which is not that easy to accomplish.

But the good thing is that maybe there's another way. Maybe you can make your wallet support some standard connection method, that is common to all major dApps, possibly including that one you are targeting.

Maybe [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3wallet/about) fits the bill, so you can implement support for it in your wallet and this opens your wallet to all major dApps in web3.